# Adding through vectors

Tags: java, object, vector, addition

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Vector vec = new Vector();

        vec.add(new Team(1, "Manchester City", 38, 64, 89));
        vec.add(new Team(2, "Manchester United", 38, 56, 89));
        vec.add(new Team(3, "Arsenal", 38, 25, 70));
        vec.add(new Team(4, "Tottenham", 38, 25, 69));
        vec.add(new Team(5, "Newcastle", 38, 5, 65));

        int points = 0;
        int total = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        {
            points = ((Team) vec.elementAt(i)).getPoints();
            total += points;
        }
        System.out.println("Total Points: " + points);


    }
```

Could anyone help me out here, all i want to do is add all of the values of the last parameter in my objects together.

What i have below is just printing out the value of the last object(65).

I'd say its something small i'm doing wrong but if anyone could point it out for me, that'd be great.

Comment: `System.out.println("Total Points: " + total);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 System.out.println("Total Points: " + points);
                                        |
                                        look here it should be total.
```

change like this.

```
 System.out.println("Total Points: " + total);
```

or

change

```
points = ((Team) vec.elementAt(i)).getPoints();
total += points;
```

to

```
points += ((Team) vec.elementAt(i)).getPoints();
total = points;
```

Comment: Ha i feel silly now, guess i'm not with it today. Thanks for the help Prabhakaran

Comment: I just did there, needed to wait like 9 minutes first ha

Answer (score 2):

You can use foreach instead of for:

```
for(Object t:vec)
{
    total += ((Team)t).getPoints();
}
```